# Ionic file transfer error

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the cordova file transfer and file plugins to go to a server and get some data and image. I am then saving this data to the device's storage, the data format is a .json file and some images. I am able to save all the data to the device.

My problem happens when I try to use that data. When I try to load the local data, I get

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///android_asset/www/Android/data/com.mydomain.myApp/files/data.json
```

From the console log messages I can see that 'file:///android_asset/www/' is being added to the path when it is being called, is this correct?

I am using the angularjs $resource service.

```
var localData = $resource(filePath);
```

If anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was doing this all wrong. Because the data is local I shouldn't be making a `$resource` request. I have instead used `readAsText(path, file)` from the [ngCordova documentation](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/).

Essentially when I am saving the data to a .json file it is being treated as a text file, I can then use the method about in conjunction with `JSON.parse(data);` this can then be set to my scope and used in the same way as the remote data.

P.S. I have tried with both 'cordova.file.dataDirectory' and 'cordova.file.externalDataDirectory' and both worked in my tests. And the info offered by 'Fabio Antunes' in this post is worth a read.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you are storing the files in the right folder?

Reading the [Cordova File Plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files) you get this:

> Where to Store Files
>
> As of v1.2.0, URLs to important file-system
>   directories are provided. Each URL is in the form
>   file:///path/to/spot/, and can be converted to a DirectoryEntry using
>   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL().
>
> cordova.file.applicationDirectory - Read-only directory where the
>   application is installed. (iOS, Android, BlackBerry 10)
>
> cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory - Root directory of the
>   application's sandbox; on iOS this location is read-only (but specific
>   subdirectories [like /Documents] are read-write). All data contained
>   within is private to the app. ( iOS, Android, BlackBerry 10)
>
> cordova.file.dataDirectory - Persistent and private data storage
>   within the application's sandbox using internal memory (on Android, if
>   you need to use external memory, use .externalDataDirectory). On iOS,
>   this directory is not synced with iCloud (use .syncedDataDirectory).
>   (iOS, Android, BlackBerry 10)
>
> cordova.file.cacheDirectory - Directory for cached data files or any
>   files that your app can re-create easily. The OS may delete these
>   files when the device runs low on storage, nevertheless, apps should
>   not rely on the OS to delete files in here. (iOS, Android, BlackBerry
>   10)
>
> cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory - Application space
>   on external storage. (Android)
>
> cordova.file.externalDataDirectory - Where to put app-specific data
>   files on external storage. (Android)
>
> cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory - Application cache on external
>   storage. (Android)
>
> cordova.file.externalRootDirectory - External storage (SD card) root.
>   (Android, BlackBerry 10)
>
> cordova.file.tempDirectory - Temp directory that the OS can clear at
>   will. Do not rely on the OS to clear this directory; your app should
>   always remove files as applicable. (iOS)
>
> cordova.file.syncedDataDirectory - Holds app-specific files that
>   should be synced (e.g. to iCloud). (iOS)
>
> cordova.file.documentsDirectory - Files private to the app, but that
>   are meaningful to other application (e.g. Office files). (iOS)
>
> cordova.file.sharedDirectory - Files globally available to all
>   applications (BlackBerry 10)

Based on this list my advice is for you to usually store files in cordova.file.dataDirectory doing this:

```
var targetPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + filename + extension
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("http://some.server.com/download.php");

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    targetPath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
);
```

It's both compatible with iOS and Android.

For example you can open your downloaded image using the `targetPath`  variable:

```
//On your controller assign it to the scope
$scope.targetPath = targetPath;

//then on your view just use it as the src for your img
<img ng-src="targetPath">
```

Comment: Thank you for the info above it is really helpful. I am using 'cordova.file.externalDataDirectory' to store my data, is this incorrect. I was told to use this as it will all be deleted when the app is uninstalled by users (keeping the device clean)?

Comment: That's wrong, as far as I know whichever data storage you choose it will be deleted when you uninstall the app. I use `cordova.file.dataDirectory` and when I uninstall my apps all of the data I downloaded is removed